# Construct an URL with data of login to redirect to another app with parameter

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

When a user finish to login, I'd like to redirect to another app(app_2). At the end of the url I'd like that the URL be `.../app_2/username`. And not `.../app_2`

Here's my code:

**app_2/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
def index(request,user_name)):
    return render(request,'app_2/index.html',{'user_key':user_name})
```

**app_2/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
    path('<user_name>', views.index),
]
```

In another app, i made a test.

**app_1/views.py**

```
if Authentification(request,username,password):
    request.session['username_key'] = username
    return redirect('/app_2/',{'key_app_1':username})
```

Comment: App_1 is your main project directory ?

Comment: After authentication you want to redirect to App_2 url with username ? Like  a .com/app_2/username ?

Comment: Yes. App_1 is whete i have the login form; and if the authenticate is okey, i want to go to the app_2 by having in the url the username.